# Calculate mean of multiple rows using grouping variables

Tags: r, plyr, psych

I am trying to calculate an overall mean of multiple classes. Currently the database is in long format. I tried selecting first ID number (group variable 1), then a dummy variable (stem=1) classes that I am interested in (grouping variable 2), and then calculating one GPA mean (i.e., stem GPA mean) for the grades received in interested classes (stem=1).

I have an attached an example of the database below. Overall,, I am trying figure out how to calculate stem GPA for each student.

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlTxc.jpg)

I have tried using library(psych), describeBy(data, dataset$id, dataset$stem), but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: easy base R, try `help('aggregate')` to get you started..

Comment: In addition to `aggregate`,  `?ave` could also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the `dplyr` package for these operations. Try e.g.

```
 df %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise(mean_class=mean(class))
```

For instance, using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mean_disp = mean(disp))
```

will give you all the means of `disp` based on the grouping variable `cyl`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you clarify the meaning of %>% ? Thank you!

Comment: That is the so-called pipe-operator. It takes whatever is on the left and gives it as an argument to whatever is on the right. For instance, `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)` should be read "take the dataset `mtcars`, then `group` it by cyclinder size, then... it is equivalent to the command `group_by(mtcars, cyl)` since the first argument of `group_by` is a dataframe.

Comment: On a more general note, this problem belongs to the `split-apply-combine` theme. If you google this, you will find many more ways to do the above. Moreover, you seem pretty new to stackoverflow, and that is ok, I have been there myself. ;) Just want to say that it is generally advisable to post a `minimal reproducable example` (google it) with the desired output when posting here.